# Writing an Address to a Pointer in a struct with a function fails

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have two structs `pbuf` and `netif`, and assigned two variables (`local_pbuf`, `local_netif`) with them. These variables hold some data. There is another struct called `wrapper_p_n`, which holds two pointers of the type `pbuf` and `netif`. My goal is to write a function which hand over the variables `local_pbuf` and `local_netif` by *call by reference* and then wraps the two pointers in a single struct called `wrapper_p_n`. Then I want to use *call by reference* to give `wrapper_p_n` to another function. Unfortunately I get the Error message:
[Error] cannot convert 'pbuf**' to 'pbuf*' in assignment

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct pbuf{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct netif{
    int c;
    int d;
};

struct wrapper_p_n{ // wrapper for pbuf- and netif-struct pointer
    struct pbuf *wp_val_p;
    struct netif *wp_val_n;
};

void rx_local_p_n(struct pbuf *rx_pbuf, struct netif *rx_netif)
{
    // wrap the received pointer
    
    struct wrapper_p_n *local_w_p_n;
    
    local_w_p_n->wp_val_p = &rx_pbuf;
    local_w_p_n->wp_val_n = &rx_netif;
    
    /*Passing *local_w_p_n pointer to another function: Example: */
    /*ex_function(&local_w_p_n)*/
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    // give values to local_pbuf and netif
    struct pbuf local_pbuf;
    local_pbuf.a = 1;
    local_pbuf.b = 2;
    
    struct netif local_netif;
    local_netif.c = 3;
    local_netif.d = 4;
    
    //passing pbuf- and netif-stuct to function
    rx_local_p_n(&local_pbuf, &local_netif);
        
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function `void rx_local_p_n` you pass in pointers to the `pbuf` and `netif` struct. These are already pointers and do not need to be assigned to your wrapper struct using the address of operator (&): by doing so you are getting the memory location of the pointer itself. That is why it is complaining about not being able to convert `pbuf** to pbuf*`.

**Solution**

1. `local_w_p_n->wp_val_p = &rx_pbuf;` to `local_w_p_n->wp_val_p = rx_pbuf;`
2. `local_w_p_n->wp_val_n = &rx_netif;` to  `local_w_p_n->wp_val_n = rx_netif;`

Answer (score 1):

Here in the function params,
`struct pbuf *rx_pbuf, struct netif *rx_netif`

Are already pointers, you do not need to get the address of the pointers, the `&` is useful when your variables are allocated on the stack and the function call needs a pointer.

As a result, this is the code change

```
local_w_p_n->wp_val_p = rx_pbuf;
local_w_p_n->wp_val_n = rx_netif;
```

Comment: Thanks for yur help. I added you code and now the code is compiled. Unfortunately when I execute the programm I get "return value 3221225477". Do you have any Idea why?

Comment: I would recommend you'd create another question for that, without you sharing your code again it will be impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the original posted code `local_w_p_n` was defined as a pointer but not initialized; the attempts to assign members should crash since `local_w_p_n` would be leftover stack data, not a valid address. Try this example:

```
void rx_local_p_n(struct pbuf *rx_pbuf, struct netif *rx_netif)
{
    // define as a struct instead of a struct *
    struct wrapper_p_n local_w_p_n;

    // assign from func args without &
    // switch from -> to .
    local_w_p_n.wp_val_p = rx_pbuf;
    local_w_p_n.wp_val_n = rx_netif;

    x_function(&local_w_p_n);
}
```